# Finding the amplitude of the difference between two sinusoids

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, real-numbers

I have the following function:

$$y(t)=a\sin(wt+p)-b\sin(wt+p+\frac{2\pi}{3})\tag1$$

> Question: what is the amplitude of the function $y(t)$ in terms of $a,b,w$ and $p$?

I thought I can find:

$$\frac{\partial y(t)}{\partial t}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space t=\dots\tag2$$

And than use that $t$ to find $\hat{y}(t)$. But I can not solve $(2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial y(t)}{\partial t}=w \left(a \cos (p+t w)+b \sin \left(p+t w+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\right)$$ Let $p+t w=x$ and you need to solve
$$a \cos (x)+b \sin \left(x+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)=0$$ Expand the sine
$$(2 a+b) \cos (x)+b\sqrt{3}  \sin (x)=0$$ which looks to be simple.